# подключение css файла размещенного на github

Tags: html, css, github

загрузил на github простенький css файл, вот линк: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/an-2-an/coo-cssl-framework/master/cool-styler.css

подключаю его в локальном html файле по ссылке вот таким образом

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/an-2-an/coo-cssl-framework/master/cool-styler.css">`

он его вроде правильно находит, но ничего не происходит

если убрать `type="text/css"` или добавить
если вместо этого вставить `type="text/plain"` все ровно так же

как обойти?

Comment: Используй GitHub pages.

Comment: мне интересно именно отдельный файл подключить

Comment: а хотя... надо подумать, спасибо

Comment: Так никто не мешает потом с pages забирать отдельный файл. Просто raw не предназначен для встраивания в html-страницы

Comment: Будет какой-нибудь `https://an-2-an.github.io/cool-styler.css`

Comment: Вы хоть переходили по ссылке? Редиректит на https://raw.githubusercontent.com/an-2-an/coo-cssl-framework/master/cool-styler.css

Comment: вариант с pages действительно работает

Comment: @daemonhk, поправил ссылку, результат такой же